# Help me express a statement about a set models using set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to express the statement "the set $S$ consists of models $m$ such that their number $n$ equals to or greater than 1001" using set builder notation. I suppose there are several ways I can do that. Here's what I've come up with:

$S=\{m|n\in\mathbb N\ \land n \ge 1001 \}$

or

$S=\{m|n\in\mathbb N\ , n \ge 1001\}$.

The thing I'm worried about is that so far the connection between the models $m$ and their number $n$ is not clearly stressed inside the braces.

So I have two questions:
(1) which of the two expressions I've written mathematicians or logicians would prefer, that with the "$\land$" operator or that with a comma? Or is it just a matter of taste?

(2) How to formally stress that $n$ is the number of models $m$? What's the way to do that (maybe I should use an index or anything like that)?

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is the number $n$ a property of $m$? Like every element of $S$ has this property greater than 1000?

Comment: You do indeed need to relate $m$ and $n$ for your set builder notation to make any sense. Regarding (1), words are better, just remember that you are writing for humans. Regarding (2), you have not told us what a *model* is, and without knowing that, it's hard to answer your questions.

Comment: It is not a property of individual models $m$, rather it is a property of the whole set $S$ describing the number of its models.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Does it mean I should be happy with what I've come up with? That is, I don't need to express the relation between $m$ and $n$ at all?

Answer (score 0):

For number of models, you can do $n = |S|$; $|S|$ is the number of elements in $S$, or it's size. But you still need to specify what kind of object $m$ is. For example, in your statements, you 'said' that $n$ is a natural number by the expression $n\in\mathbb N$. Mathematically, $n\in\mathbb N$ is saying that $n$ is taken from a set $\mathbb N$, which we have denoted to be the set of all natural numbers.

So in a similar fashion, if you could define $M$ to be the set of all possible models $m$, then you could write your desired statement as $$S=\{m \in M\}, \; |S| \geq 1001$$

Or more compactly, $$S \subset M, \; |S| \geq 1001$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's just an abstract statement and I suppose a model could mean "a computer model" or anything of the kind. So I assume that we can't have a set which has a negative or any other number models, that's why I said that $n$ must belong to the set of all natural numbers.

Comment: Abstract statements are challenging to translate into set builder notation. Oftentimes, the simplest approach is to mix in English with maths; e.g. $\text{s.t. } m \text{ is a model}$